# Dynamic JTextField Inside JPanel Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

im doing a project where i have to create a bar with some scrolling text...
The problem is that i may have to highlight the background of the text and for that im thinking in use JTextField so i can color the background...
My current problem is making the JTextField appear inside the JPanel... this is what i have so far (the design):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdfyZ.png

[image]

the Red rectangle will be to display the JTextField with the messages and the green rectangle will be to display some advertising, please note that they are only colored now for i make sure where are the JPanels, when the program is done they will became white and the color will be made by the JTextFields...

The next problem, may be the moving text, I dont have that implemented yet but i guess it will be easy, i will leave here an ideia for you tell me if im going in a good way or if i should change to a better ideia...
So, i want to do something like the news:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH2je.jpg

[image]

So, i want that my text go from right to the left, i will create a runnable that for every 10-50 ms change the location of my text some points to the left... about the text displaying im thinking in create and LinkedList of JTextField and then show them in the panel...

Thank you in advance and if you can help me displaying the JTextField on the panel i will appreciate, alse, if you can tell me if my ideia about the moving text is the most correct or not...
Thank you all for yout time!

Edit: I have your "MyPanel" code and in the main class of the frame i have a method that add the MyPanel to the panel where i want them to be...

```
createMsg();
 PanelMsg.repaint();
}
  public void createMsg() {
    MyPanel test = new MyPanel("teste", "1");
    PanelMsg.add(test);      
}
```

The PanelMsg is the top panel, the problem may be because im not using any layout and that is because im afraid that this dont work so i was trying with free design. I said that im afraid that doesnt work because i need to make the text role and the layouts block their contents...

Comment: this hard to be possible with plain vanilla JTextField, there must be something (theoretically whatever implements Scrollable) inside JScrollPane (with disabled JScrollBars)

Comment: not sure if that is the best option since i have a list of message to display and when this list finish i have to display the first one again without break the chain, so thats why maybe is better get the current X and move them...

Comment: Why not just build a `String` the simply drops a character off the start (and may be adds it the end)?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your own JPanel with two JLabels. set the background for both labels.

```
public MyPanel extends JPanel{
private JLabel topLabel;
private JLabel bottomLabel;

MyPanel(String news, String ad){

topLabel = new JLabel(news);
bottomLabel = new JLabel(ad);

//set your layout

}

}
```

Now, add multiple instances of MyPanel to your JPanel.

```
public class Main extends JPanel{
Main(){
//other stuffs
MyPanel abc = new MyPanel("Stack", "Overflow");
MyPanel xyz = new MyPanel("Hello", "World");
add(abc);
add(xyz);
//Use Flow layout
//other stuffs
}
```

}

Comment: Thats a good ideia, but my problem is how i can show it on my Main panel?

Comment: Thats a good ideia but my problem is show this new panel or other item on JPanel... i have tried use the repaint, paint, validate, relavidade, pack but nothing works :\

Comment: @JoãoSilva: call repaint after you add each component. It should work fine. Also, paste your code where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

> im doing a project where i have to create a bar with some scrolling text... The problem is that i may have to highlight the background of the text and for that im thinking in use JTextField so i can color the background...

I would use JLabels. You can set the background of a JLabel, you just need to use:

```
label.setOpaque(true);
```

Check out [Marquee Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/) for a component to do the scrolling for you.